Discord.py startswith not working even on the correct phrase
I have just started to learn bots in discord. but the issue is that whenever i try
message.content.startswith('Hello')
then even after writing 'Hello' , even copying and pasting or making the bot return the string and pasting it within discord, it doesnt count it as correct input. But, if I make the bot write 'Hello', it recognises it just fine. pls help, here is the code
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print('Roger victim. I m in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event

async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    if message.content.startswith('Hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hola !')
    
    else:
        await message.channel.send('no, Hello')


client.run('token value')

the code is showing this output
(https://i.sstatic.net/JpvYx3p2.png)
I have tried copying the 'Hello' from the editor, discord, the bot; and replacing it with simpler '.' or '/' to see if it works, but none did.
the bot is running, so i doubt any spelling error.
i m using discord on my phone if that helps.
the bot identifies the text as correct when I make it write the text itself and identify it.
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print('Roger victim. I m in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event

async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        await message.channel.send('Hello')
        if message.content.startswith('Hello'):
            await message.channel.send('Hola no mark')
        return
    
    if message.content.startswith('Hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hola !')
    
    else:
        await message.channel.send('no')


client.run('token value')

the output of this code is
(https://i.sstatic.net/jH306kFd.png)

Enable message content intent. Default doesn't have it enabled. Intent.default doc

How do you know if it reads the message? Try printing out to the console. Defaults intents shouldn't be able to read message content.

printing my message on the console, I can see that my message is coming in as empty, but the mesage the bot sends can be read. How to fix it? thanks for helping me find the problem

A commented by Brawldude2, I was missing an intent for message recieve. Thus, the bot was somehow able to read its own message correctly but not mine, the quick fix was to add the intent message_content from https://discord.com/developers/applications >> bot >> enable message_intent
then adding the lines to the code:
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

